# rewriterule fine, but not redirecting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

-PROBLEM:   I want to redirect the url of a javascript file by using htaccess:

-->From:

```
     http://www.domain.co.uk/tracking/tracking.js
```

-->To:

```
     http://www.domain.co.uk/templates/domain.co.uk/js/tracking.js
```

-MY HTTACESS (ALL THE TESTER ONLINE GIVE POSITIVE):

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^tracking/tracking\.js$ http://www.domain.co.uk/Templates/domain.co.uk/js/tracking.js [L,R]
```

-RESULT

```
    Not Found
    The requested URL /tracking/tracking.js was not found on this server.
    Apache/2.2.0 (Fedora) Server at domain.co.uk Port 80
```

-FOLDER STRUCTURE

```
  /...
    |
    /http
       |/Templates
       |      |/domain.co.uk
       |            |/js
       |               | - tracking.js
       |- .htaccess
       |- index.php
```

Because along the day I was testing many different ways, I'm starting to think is not because of the rewriterule, but if It's not that, what might be?

Comment: Could you indicate which directory contains this `.htaccess` file. It looks like the rule isn't kicking in. This could be due to the relative path.

Comment: yes, I edited the post to show the folder structure, thanks a lot

Comment: It is the same domain. Try: `RewriteRule ^tracking/tracking\.js$ Templates/domain.co.uk/js/tracking.js [L,R,NC]`

Comment: exactly the same result, not found etc...thanks

Comment: Make sure to check your error log from apache.  I see the "result" you've posted is the page that it produces not a log. In trying to mimic your problem I got the permissions wrong on my `.htaccess` file and caused the server to produce the same `Not Found` result.  **However when I fixed this everything worked just fine.**  What you've posted so far should work. It's possible that the error log will contain more details about what failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should include all basic directives for the rewrite to work. Like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Then the rewrite rule
RewriteRule ^tracking/tracking\.js Templates/domain.co.uk/js/tracking.js [L,R,NC]
```

If still doesn't work, the problem most probably is with the  Apache configuration file.

**This rule set should be in .htaccess file at root directory**

Comment: Giving this a +1 as `FollowSymlinks` is the setting I always forget you need.